# Why is every path I provide for creating a keystore an "Illegal option"?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

So I'm so close to having my app ready to upload to the PlayStore, but I can't get KeyStore figured out. I am using flutter, which provides what I need from java in order to run keytool. 
I get into the right directory, ( I just followed the docs on this process from flutter.dev) C:\Users\Jake Gill\AndroidStudio\jre\bin
I've gone through the process a thousand different ways of adding keystore passwords and my name and city and all that just for it to tell me that the path I provided for the key.jks to be added to is an illegal option. 
I'm using this from flutter.dev:

keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\USER_NAME\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key

When I change "USER_NAME" to my dir(Jake Gill), it says: Illegal option:  Gill\key.jks
This was the immediate error once I hit enter to start the password entering stage.

When I change my dir to something else that I know will at least take me through the steps of making a password and such, this is what it returns:

[Storing c:\Users\key.jks]
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\Users\key.jks (Access is denied)

Someone please help...

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/keytool.html) "Option values must be enclosed in quotation marks when they contain a blank (space)." and `c:\Users\Jake Gill\key.jks` contains a space. Therefore, enclose it in quotation marks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a path contains spaces, you need to wrap it in quotation marks or escape the spaces. That goes for ALL commands, not just keytool.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore "c:\Users\USER_NAME\key.jks" -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

(For that reason, I usually just avoid using spaces in directory names, and especially in user names.)

And your second location doesn't work because only the admin is allowed to read and write stuff in C:\Users. You could use C:\Users\Public.